# How to reconnect to the backend with HAProxy

Tags: networking, haproxy, high-availability

I'm new in working with HAProxy. 
I couldn't figure out how to make HAProxy to reconnect to backend that was down and started up back again.

I have a configuration of two backend servers. When they are running and I start HAProxy all works OK. The handshake is passed. Then I stop one of the backend and the traffic correctly goes to the server that is  keep running. But then, when I start up the stopped server again HAProhy does not recognize that. Only after HAProxy service restart it can again connect.

How to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAProxy backend health checking mechanism:

```
backend farm1
   server s1 192.168.1.10:80 check
   server s2 192.168.1.11:80 check
```

More info:
http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#check

Comment: If the backend went down the health check fail. That's OK, but if the backend is up again the health check still fail until HAProxy is restarted.

Comment: try (for each server):  
`server s1 192.168.1.10:80 check inter 2000 fall 3 rise 2`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Did not work for me. When the backend is down only restart or refresh makes it status up again in HAProxy.
I do the refresh with 
haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)